# How to get specific object from object prototype

Tags: javascript

My object is as below

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKaK8.png)

As per above object how can get [[Scopes]] object values.

Comment: @selmansamet you try and copy the value of chrome console output into the post. It's pretty tricky

Comment: Explain what you are trying to do, what libraries you are using, don't just link randomly to an image and expect a magical helping hand.

Comment: @JuanCortés it is not a random image. In my opinion the question was pretty clear.

Comment: @EECOLOR Glad you are willing to do what you did, have an upvote. I never said the image was random, I said he randomly linked to it but that's semantics.

Answer (score 2):

You can see it in the Chrome console as follows:

```
function Test() {
  this.Test = () => {}   
}
```

Then:

```
new Test()
```

The console will display the following:

```
Test {Test: ƒ}
  Test: () => {}
    arguments: (...)
    caller: (...)
    length: 0
    name: ""
    __proto__: ƒ ()
    [[FunctionLocation]]: VM165:2
    [[Scopes]]: Scopes[1]
      0: Global {type: "global", name: "", object: Window}
  __proto__: Object
```

The `[[...]]` entries are extra information that Chrome has available. While it is displayed by the console I do not think you will be able to access it using Javascript.

You can however right-click it and select 'Store as global variable'. Then you can access it in the console:

```
> temp1         // Scopes[1]
> temp1[0]      // Global
> temp1[0].type // "global"
```